# Spring root and servlet context with Java config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm running a Spring application in a Servlet 3.0+ environment to programmatically configure the servlet context using all Java configuration. My question (with details below): how is a project structured to support component scanning for both root and web application contexts without duplicating component initialization?

As I understand it, there are two contexts in which to register Spring beans. First, the root context is where non-servlet-related components go. For example batch jobs, DAOs, etc. Second, the servlet context is where servlet-related components go such as controllers, filters, etc.

I've implemented a WebApplicationInitializer to register these two contexts just as the JavaDoc in WebApplicationInitializer specifies with a AppConfig.class and DispatcherConfig.class.

I want both to automatically find their respective components so I've added @ComponentScan to both (which is resulting in my Hibernate entities being initiated twice). Spring finds these components by scanning some specified base package. Does that mean I need to put all my DAO-related objects in a separate package from the controllers? If so, that'd be quite inconvenient as I generally like to package by functionality (as opposed to type).

Code snippets...

WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
}
```

WebAppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AppConfig.class)
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just define what you want to scan for in each configuration. In general your root configuration should scan for everything but `@Controller`s and your web configuration should only detect `@Controller`s.

You can accomplish this by using the [`includeFilters`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#includeFilters--) and [`excludeFilters`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters--) attributes of the [`@ComponentScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation. When using include filters, in this case, you also need to disable using the default filters by setting [`useDefaultFilters`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#useDefaultFilters--) to `false`.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={@Filter(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller.class)})
public class AppConfig {}
```

And for your `WebConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AppConfig.class, useDefaultFilters=false, includeFilters={@Filter(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller.class)})
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {}
```

In addition, you need to import the `@Filter` annotation:

```
import static org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot this solves for packaging by functionality problem as well!

Comment: AppConfig: 
@ComponentScan(
        excludeFilters={ @ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class) }
)

Comment: WebAppConfig: 
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses=AppConfig.class
        , useDefaultFilters = false
        , includeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class) }
)

Comment: You can add a static import for the `Filter`.

Comment: Won't this create two copies of every bean that AppConfig defines, one which the root context creates and another that the dispatcher context creates?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: 
Yes, you should define seperate component scans per context, thus modeling your project differently and extracting the DAO into a seperate name-space (package).

The longer answer is split into two parts, one regarding the servlet contexts and the other regarding modeling a project.

Regarding root and servlet contexts: You have defined correctly the different responsibilities of root context and servlet context. This is an understanding most developers tend to miss and it is very important. 

Just to clarify a bit more on this subject, you can create one root context and several (0+) servlet contexts. All of the beans defined in your root context will be available for all servlet contexts but beans defined in each servlet context will be not be shared with other servlet contexts (different spring containers).

Now since you have multiple spring containers and you use component scan on the same packages then beans are created twice, once per container.
To avoid this you can do a few things:

1. Use one container and not two, meaning you can define only the root container or only the servlet container (I have seen many applications like this).
2. Seperate your beans into different places and provide each container its unique component scan. remember that all of the beans defined in the root container are available to use in the servlet container (you do not need to define them twice).

Lastly, a few words regarding project modeling. I personally like to write my project in layers, thus separating my code into controllers (application layer), business logic (bl layer) and DAO (database layer).
Modeling like this helps in many ways, including this root/servlet context issue you have encountered.
There are tons of information regarding layered architecture, here is a quick peed: [wiki-Multilayered_architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture)

Comment: Packaging by layer is a bad practice imho because you loose encapsulation, you try to hide everything behind a service layer but make everything public because you have seperated everything by layer.

Comment: I disagree, it all depends on how you module your project. for example, you can supply an api and multiple implementations. Another example is that modeling correctly can produce multiple building blocks and enable you to share different parts of your code. Meaning, in this example, that you can call your service layer not only though "one set of controller" but multiple protocols (tcp, rest, thrift...) and they all use the same service building block,

Comment: You should combine both approaches.. .Your business should be structered by finctionality and eveyrthing else (web, ws, rest, jms) is an small integration layer for your functionality. You should protect your domain and with a technical layer everything is public and there goes your protection.

Comment: what is "everything is public"? If you model your project correctly then you do not loose encapsulation nor protection! The opposite is true, you gain loose coupling and finer granularity. The only thing that is public are APIs between layer.

Comment: and that is the whole problem. You want to protect everything behind a service but your repository/dao is public, all of your "domain" objects are public (including the constructors) so you basically loose everything you are trying to achieve. If you put everything in a single functional package, say `com.yourapp.user` you can only make your service public with either your `User` object or a DTO (or fine grained event objects). That way you have true encapsulation and protection.

Comment: A layered architecture means that each layer has its domain objects - they are not shared, so there is no one place where you place all of your objects. controllers have DTOs, BLL has its bl domain and data layer has DAOs. They are different and do not be structured in the same way. So the dao are not visible outside of the dal, they are not see from the service layer.

Comment: I think we mean the same, layers for me are conceptual and not physical and should be packed by functionionality/domain/usecase (whatever you like to call it). There should be no `.service` etc packages.

Comment: Can you explain more regarding "Use one container and not two, meaning you can define only the root container or only the servlet container (I have seen many applications like this)."?

Does that mean I would pass the rootContext to the DispatcherServlet constructor?

Comment: Regarding the layered approach discussed above... I also structure my code with layers while packaging by functionality (which I'd have to stop doing if I follow approach #2 listed above). For example, I can have a com.example.myapp.user package which contains UserController, UserService, UserRepository, UserEntity, etc. This way, everything "user" related is part of this package and at the same time follows an MVC layered approach within the implementations.

Comment: Regarding the multiple containers, you can just ignore one of them. For example, you can ignore the root container - do not code it (comment out the first three lines in your example). You will be left with only one spring container holding all of your application beans.

Comment: Regarding the layered approach: I have a clear separation between all layers, each layer is even a different maven module, so in my case I will never have a singe package containing all user logic. Modeling like this forces me to separate the concerns of each layer. meaning that the controller layer is responsible for the "external" API (e.g. REST) where the service layer can be modeled differently (changes in one layer does not affect the another) and the same goes for the DAL. It also enables to re-use layers inside other applications (e.g. use the 'user' data layer in other apps)

Comment: "It also enables to re-use layers inside other applications (e.g. use the 'user' data layer in other apps)"
That's a great point, I hadn't thought about it that way. I probably won't do it this way, though, this particular project is too small to warrant the extra overhead. Thanks a lot for all the information you've provided this has been extremely helpful.